# How to put value of echo pipe netcat commands into variable

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, echo, netcat

I have this command succession:

```
echo -ne "/dev/shm/test.sh" | netcat 89.196.167.2 4567
```

and let's say it return a string like, for example "Hello...bla".
On the 89.196.167.2 system, I have made a server that takes ssh commands, executes them, and returns the result to the client. That ssh program is running OK; it returns what I need, so that is not the problem.

I want to put this returned value, "Hello...bla", into a variable and use it.
If I try this:

```
var=echo -ne "/dev/shm/test.sh" | netcat 89.196.167.2 4567;echo "$var"
```

it doesn't work. Bash returns this:

```
-bash: -ne: command not found
```

Can you please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks. i.e.:

```
var=`echo -ne "/dev/shm/test.sh" | netcat 89.196.167.2 4567`
```

Comment: Don't use backticks. They don't nest and are not always easy to distinguish from single quotes. It's better to use `$(...)` instead: `var=$(echo -ne "/dev/shm/test.sh" | netcat 89.196.167.2 4567)`

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Ok! I'll do that! Thank you!

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker, though backticks are obsolete and have all sort of issues, they do nest.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas But they only nest in aspirin bottles.